# How to use strtotime in MySQL Select Query and increment date

Tags: php

I would like to know how to property format a date which I have inside my DB when selected and in the same time increment it with 30 days. For Example.

My SQL SELECT date row is the following:

```
DATE_FORMAT(c.proposal_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS expiration_date
```

So once this is selected I would like to display this date but with 30 days incremented:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days", $row['expiration_date'])); ?>
```

Right now I am getting an error: **Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered**

Any help to properly solve this syntax's problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ADDDATE

```
 DATE_FORMAT( ADDDATE(c.proposal_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AS expiration_date_30
```

Answer (score 2):

Second argument of `strtotime()` should be an int timestamp.
But you could do it like this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$row['expiration_date']} +30 days"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the manual, strtotime second parameter is an integer:

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

So you need to give it the time stamp:

```
<?php 
$time = strtotime($row['expiration_date']));
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days", $time ) ); ?>
```